# PHP Monolog log file locking behavior differs in CGI and CLI

Tags: php, laravel-5, locking, monolog

I have a Laravel application that I develop and test on my Windows machine. It uses `php-cgi.exe` (FastCGI) to run the application, and `php artisan queue:work` to run the listeners for queued jobs.

When I have the job queue listener running, I am unable to modify the log file (`storage/logs/laravel.log`) because the OS tells me that the file is locked by another process. However, the fact that the FastCGI process is writing to the same file doesn't seem to be a problem.

Why can I not modify the log file while the job queue listener is running?